# My Telegram Bot was added to a spam channel. How to remove it?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, fraud-prevention

I have a Telegram bot. It was added as an Admin (but without any rights) to a private spam channel. This channel sends to my bot messages twice a minute. How could I remove my bot from this channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch a message from this group and then use `leaveGroup` method with this `chat_id`. Also may be a good idea to add this id to some kind of blacklist and leave this chat automaticaly